# Career advice as a junior software developer

Tags: career-development, software-development, careers, junior

I will be graduating in next month and will be starting my first job as a software developer. I am planning for acquiring 2-3 yrs of experience and then apply for masters. I am looking for extracurricular activities like hackathon or open source contribution as a junior software developer that will help me in my profile building. Any kind of advice and even your experience while being a junior software developer will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Not only is this question opinion based, but it's so vague we can't say much besides "keep coding"

Comment: push for more money, and move on to your second job as soon as possible.  take care that *some* master's are useless - if you're going to be a technical ultra-specialist (in some field or the other) it's fantastic, but otherwise can be a waste.

Comment: Does only job activities matter, extracurricular activities like hackathon and all do they improve my profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will be graduating in next month and will be starting my first job
> as a software developer.
>
> I am looking for extracurricular activities as a junior software
> developer that will help me in my profile building.

Ask your new employer/manager to make suggestions. There can sometimes be opportunities inside the company to receive additional training. They may also have programs that expose new employees to additional parts of the company to enhance their understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The number one thing you can do in your new job is to perform well in your new job.  Your job experience is what companies will look for.  If you are in a defined area the best thing you can do is be known in the area.  This means doing a good job and having advocates who will later want to hire you.

Hobbies/interests don't really mean much to most of the world.  I guess they flesh you out as a person, but hiring managers care about your demonstrated skills.